# Как объединить несколько строк в одну

Tags: python

Хочу написать программу которая выводит случайное число. Вот код:

```
import random
determinant_number_of_letters = random.randint(1,5)

def real_letter(determinant_of_letter):
    determinant_of_letter = random.randint(1,10)
    adder = []
    if determinant_of_letter == 1:
        print("a")
    if determinant_of_letter == 2:
        print("b")
    if determinant_of_letter == 3:
        print("c")
    if determinant_of_letter == 4:
        print("d")
    if determinant_of_letter == 5:
        print("e")
    if determinant_of_letter == 6:
        print("f")
    if determinant_of_letter == 7:
        print("g")
    if determinant_of_letter == 8:
        print("h")
    if determinant_of_letter == 9:
        print("i")
    if determinant_of_letter == 10:
        print("j")

if determinant_number_of_letters == 1:
    real_letter(random.randint(1,10))
if determinant_number_of_letters == 2:
    for i in range(0,2):
        real_letter(random.randint(1,10))
if determinant_number_of_letters == 3:
    for i in range(0, 3):
        real_letter(random.randint(1,10))
if determinant_number_of_letters == 4:
    for i in range(0, 4):
        real_letter(random.randint(1,10))
if determinant_number_of_letters == 5:
    for i in range(0, 5):
        real_letter(random.randint(1,10))
```

На выходе программа выдаёт отдельные строки что то типа:

```
a
d
c
f
```

Мне же нужно что бы программа выводила их в строку так:

```
adcf
```

Подскажите как можно решить эту проблему.

Answer (score 2):

Используйте параметр `end=""` в функциях `print()`, например

```
print("a", end="")
```

Этот параметр заменит обычный символ `\n` (переход на новую строку) пустым символом, так что последующий `print()` будет продолжаться в той-же самой строке.